# Using for loop to get the values for both session arrays and existing table values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, session-variables

I have this write-up for a form that has 10 of the same inputs, stored in an array to loop through and manipulate data accordingly. Sample of the form with the input:

```
    <form id="sanFiber" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <table class="frame">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="host[]" class="field" type="text" size="15" 
           <?php if(isset($_SESSION['hostName'])){ echo "value='
           ".$_SESSION['hostName']."'";}?> /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="host[]" class="field" type="text" size="15" 
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['hostName'])){ echo"value='".$_SESSION['hostName']."'";}?> /></td>
   </tr>
       ...
   </form>
```

I have been able to create a for loop to insert new values in an existing table on the database, however, I've had trouble trying to do a Select query the same way because the values aren't pre-existing. The loop I tried only returned the first value. The conflict is that I have to loop both the Session arrays and the rows found on the database. The for loop portion for the $row values work just fine. The Session loop is where my problem lies. My Select query and for loop are as follows:

```
<?php 
include ("connect.php");
session_start();

$query = "SELECT * FROM cable_request_san_fiber_detail WHERE cable_request_id = '".$id."'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $label[]=$row['cable'];
}       
for ($i=0, $n=0; $i<count($label), $n<count($_SESSION['hostName']); $i++, $n++){
    $_SESSION['hostName'][$n]=$label[$i];
}
    header('Location:Table.php');
$conn->close();
?>
```

In my for loop, I combined two different loops: One for counting and looping through all of the Session variables and one for looping through all the rows in the table on the database. Is there any way to correctly do both for loops together or should I perform them separately?

Comment: In the first block, you're echoing `$_SESSION['hostName']` as a string.  So why are you creating an array on `$_SESSION['hostName']` in the second block?

Comment: @Devon Oh..I see what you mean. But I need the session to be an array because of the multiple input values. Should I just not echo it as a string in the first block and echo the session as an array in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a point to having `$label`?

Instead of:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $label[]=$row['cable'];
}       
for ($i=0, $n=0; $i<count($label), $n<count($_SESSION['hostName']); $i++, $n++){
    $_SESSION['hostName'][$n]=$label[$i];
}
```

Why not one loop instead of two:

```
// Clear old hostnames so you don't end up with duplicates
$_SESSION['hostName'] = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_SESSION['hostName'][] = $row['cable'];
}
```

When outputting in HTML, you would want to loop through the array:

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['hostName'] as $hostname) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="host[]" class="field" type="text" size="15" value="<?= $hostname ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: The label variable was to loop the table values for the cable label row ($row['cable') but, your single loop makes sense and looks a lot less chaotic. I'll try it out and test it on the server tomorrow and let you know the results. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Marked it as a valid answer. Your loop helped me obtain every session array value without any errors and simplified my own.

Answer (score 0):

you're in an array....trying to echo an array as a string.    In the loop do      `echo( $res= array_shift($_SESSION['hostName'])?$res:'';`

Comment: So my for loop should be more like..
`for ($i=0, $n=0; $i<count($label), $n<count($_SESSION['hostName']); $i++, $n++){
    $_SESSION['hostName'][$n]=$label[$i];
echo( $res=array_shift($_SESSION['hostName'])?$res:'';
}` and take out the echo statement within the actual form?